# How can I set selected equals to True in a DropDownList in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, razor, dropdownlistfor

I have this code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlTiposUsuarios", Model.tiposUsuarios.Select(item => new SelectListItem
                               {
                                   Value = item.Id_Tipo_Usuario.ToString(),
                                   Text = item.Nombre_Tipo_Usuario.ToString(),
                                   Selected = "select" == item.Id_Tipo_Usuario.ToString()
                               }), new { @class = "form-select", aria_label = "Default select eaxmple" })
```

I retrieve a list of four elements from SQL Server and I want to set an option html element which "selected" attribute equals true, depending query from Controller. Any tips?

Comment: Do you have a boolean in the result set or something you can use a ternary operator on to set Selected either true or false?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the `SelectList` on your `View`, create the list in your `Controller` and set it to a `ViewBag` and see how easy it becomes after that:

In your `Controller`, do this:

```
ViewBag.myddlItems = tiposUsuarios.Select(item => new SelectListItem
                               {
                                   Value = item.Id_Tipo_Usuario.ToString(),
                                   Text = item.Nombre_Tipo_Usuario.ToString()
                               });
```

and then in your View, you can construct your `DropDownList` using the `ViewBag`:

```
<select id="ddlTiposUsuarios" class="form-select" aria_label = "Default select eaxmple">
    @foreach (SelectListItem option in ViewBag.myddlItems)
    {
        <option value="@option.Value" @(option.Value == "select" ? "selected='selected'" : "")>@option.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: `tiposUsuarios` are not of type `SelectListItem`, and `option.Value.Id_Tipo_Usuario.ToString()` will never == `option`

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, you are correct. I have given an alternative approach based on your input.